# Redux Saga Behavior of Component Life-cycle

Tags: lifecycle, redux-saga

This is a general question. I have a redux saga yielding calls that update the store every x mins and show the store gets updated appropriately in the redux dev tool. In the render method of my component if I click before the data I will get a spinner and if I click after the component will render; ***HOWEVER***, in the components class the life cycle "componentWillUpdate" or "componentWillReceiveProps"  shows the connected piece in redux store as undefined in either method yet the render is able to pass the correct props; what the cluck? I'll head back to the docs but this seems odd.

```
...
    //dont usually use this for redux
    componentWillReceiveProps(){
      console.log(dailyOperations) // nothing here
    }

    componentWillUpdate(){
      console.log(dailyOperations) // nothing here
    }

    render(){
      if (dailyOperations === undefined) {
        return (<SpinnerThing />)
      else
        return (<SomeDisplayComponent data={dailyOperations} />)  //Data is here
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't at the time account for it but now it makes sense and if it helps anyone else great. It will not be there on the update for the connected redux state but through "componentWillUpdate(nextProps)" & nextProps will have it.